# Strip out content between and including h2 tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to strip the content from between the h2 tags in a string using a Regex in C#:

```
<h2>content needs removing</h2> other content...
```

I have the following Regex, which according to the Regex buddy software I used to test it, should work, but it doesn't:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"<h[0-9]>.*</h[0-9]>", String.Empty);
```

I have another Regex that is run after this to remove all other HTML tags, it is called in the same way and works fine. Can anyone help me out with why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code :

```
String sourcestring = "<h2>content needs removing</h2> other content...";
String matchpattern = @"\s?<h[0-9]>[^<]+</h[0-9]>\s?";
String replacementpattern = @"";
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementpattern));
```

`[^<]+` is more safer than `.+` because it stops collecting where it sees a `<`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Regular Expressions.

`HTML` is not a Regular Language, thus it can't be parsed correctly with a Regular Expression.

For example, your Regex would match:

```
<h2>sample</h1>
```

which is not valid. When dealing with nested structures, this would lead to unexpected results (`.*` is greedy and matches everything until the last closing `h[0-9]` tag in your input HTML string)

You can use `XMLDocument` (HTML is not XML but that would be sufficient for what you're trying to do) or you can use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: XMLDocument or XDocument will work if the HTML is well formed XML

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
string myString = "<h2>content needs removing</h2> other content...";
Console.WriteLine(myString);
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "<h[0-9]>.*</h[0-9]>", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(myString);
```

Displays:

```
<h2>content needs removing</h2> other content...
other content...
```

As expected.

If you problem is that your real case has several different heading tags, then you have an issue with the greedy * quantifier. It will create the longest match that it can. For example, if you have:

```
<h2>content needs removing</h2> other content...<h3>some more headings</h3> and some other stuff
```

You will match everything from `<h2>` to `</h3>` and replace it. To fix this, you need to use a lazy quantifier:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "<h[0-9]>.*?</h[0-9]>", string.Empty);
```

Will leave you with:

```
other content... and some other stuff
```

Note however, that this will not fix nested `<h>` tags. As @fardjad said, using Regex for HTML isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: Interesting. There must be something else going on that is causing this to not work. It's within a control in a custom-built CMS, so maybe it is not being passed through in the correct format. I'll keep digging :)